# Why is sorting an array of strings different than sorting an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I can sort the array `[1, 3, 2]` by calling the `.sort()` method on it. Optionally, I can pass in a comparison function to do things like sorting the array in reverse. This always works when the array contains Numbers.

However, when the array contains Strings, the `.sort()` method is unpredictable. It will sort the array if no optional comparison function is provided, but **will not** sort if a comparison function is provided.

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround?

I have included a code snippet below that illustrates the problem.

```js
let letters;
let numbers;

letters = ["a", "c", "b"];
numbers = [1, 3, 2];
console.log(letters.sort());                  // ["a", "b", "c"] DOES SORT
console.log(numbers.sort());                  // [1, 2, 3].      DOES SORT

letters = ["a", "c", "b"];
numbers = [1, 3, 2];
console.log(letters.sort((a, b) => a - b));   // ["a", "c", "b"] DOES NOT SORT
console.log(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));   // [1, 2, 3]       DOES SORT

letters = ["a", "c", "b"];
numbers = [1, 3, 2];
console.log(letters.sort((a, b) => b - a));   // ["a", "c", "b"] DOES NOT SORT
console.log(numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a));   // [3, 2, 1]       DOES SORT
```

Comment: What do you think subtraction means with strings?

Comment: `numbers.sort()` does _not_ work. Try `[2, 10]`.

Comment: _“Is there a workaround?”_ — Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort); use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Comment: Have you read the description of what the comparison function is supposed to return?

Answer (score 1):

Because `"a" - "b" == NaN`.

From [Array.sort docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

`Array.sort()` expects the compare function to return a numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to read the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Array sort is a weird one, but the gist of it is that the "compare function" (which is the thing you pass to `sort()` ie. `(a, b) => a - b)`) has to return a number.
You can easily test it in the browser console, and you'll see that subtracting two strings doesn't work `'a' - 'b'`.

As a workaround you can use `localeCompare` (also mentioned in the docs).

```
var letters = ["a", "c", "b"];
letters.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"When sort() is called without arguments, the array items are transformed into strings and sorted. invoking the method on numbers performs the same alphabetical sorting:"

Not mine, though

https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-sort-numbers/.